# Database Connection Going Wrong in Golang?

Tags: postgresql, http, go, heroku, web-applications

So I am using herokuapp to host a golang app for me, I am trying to make a signup form to make it so people can register and become users, but I am encountering an error in my code:
I have 2 main files, main.go and store.go, which handle the server stuff and then a /assets folder with my static html including the signup page.

Methods in main.go:

```
type User struct {
    username string `json:"username"`
    gender bool `json:"gender"`
    age int `json:"age"`
    password string `json:"password"`
    email string `json:"email"`
}

func newRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/user", getUserHandler).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/user", createUserHandler).Methods("POST")
        r.HandleFunc("/forms/login", loginUserHandler).Methods("POST")
        r.HandleFunc("/forms/signup", createUserHandler).Methods("POST")
    //ALL PAGE FUNCTIONS HERE
    r.HandleFunc("/", handler).Methods("GET")

    //Declare static file directory
    staticFileDirectory := http.Dir("./assets/")

    staticFileHandler := http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(staticFileDirectory))

    r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(staticFileHandler).Methods("GET")
    return r
}
func main() {
    router := newRouter()
    portEnv := os.Getenv("PORT")
    port := ":" + portEnv
    http.ListenAndServe(port, router)

        url := os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL")
        db, err := sql.Open("postgres", url)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Connection error: %s", err.Error())
            panic(err)
        }
        defer db.Close()

        err = db.Ping()

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Ping error: %s", err.Error())
            panic(err)
        }

        InitStore(&dbStore{db: db})
}
func createUserHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := User{}

    //Send all data as HTML form Data so parse form
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("Error: %v", err))
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    //Get the information about the user from user info
    user.username = r.Form.Get("username")
  //  user.gender, _ = strconv.ParseBool(r.Form.Get("gender"))
    user.age = 16
    user.password = r.Form.Get("password")
        cpassword := r.Form.Get("cpassword")
    user.email = r.Form.Get("email")

        if(user.password != cpassword) {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/assets/signup.html", http.StatusSeeOther)
            return
        }
        user.password = hashAndSalt([]byte(user.password))
    //Append existing list of users with a new entry
    err = store.CreateUser(&user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
  //Set Cookie with username
        addCookie(w, "username", user.username)

    http.Redirect(w, r, "/assets/", http.StatusFound)
}
```

Those are the main functions in use for this part of the web-server and the only ones that should be giving me this error response

store.go:

```
type Store interface {
    CreateUser(user *User) error
    GetUsers()([]*User, error)
}
func (store *dbStore) CreateUser(user *User) error {
    _, err := store.db.Query("INSERT INTO users(username,age,password,email) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4);",user.username,user.age,user.password,user.email)
    return err
}
var store dbStore

func InitStore(s dbStore) {
    store = s
}
```

my error code:

```
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077322+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020/02/07 04:58:18 http: panic serving (MYIP):18930: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077334+00:00 app[web.1]: goroutine 13 [running]:
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077337+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00008f400)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077339+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:1769 +0x139
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077341+00:00 app[web.1]: panic(0x725720, 0xa29b80)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077343+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/runtime/panic.go:522 +0x1b5
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077346+00:00 app[web.1]: database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, 0x7fdf40, 0xc000016048, 0xa2a301, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000055920)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077348+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1080 +0x3a
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077350+00:00 app[web.1]: database/sql.(*DB).query(0x0, 0x7fdf40, 0xc000016048, 0x798f41, 0x44, 0xc000055a30, 0x4, 0x4, 0x1, 0xc00010acc0, ...)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077352+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1513 +0x66
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077355+00:00 app[web.1]: database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0x0, 0x7fdf40, 0xc000016048, 0x798f41, 0x44, 0xc000055a30, 0x4, 0x4, 0x6d5085, 0x0, ...)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077357+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1495 +0xd1
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077359+00:00 app[web.1]: database/sql.(*DB).Query(...)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077362+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1509
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077364+00:00 app[web.1]: main.(*dbStore).CreateUser(0xa34758, 0xc000055b50, 0x20, 0xc00010acc0)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077366+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/tmp.N9S5bJfo59/.go/src/github.com/InsanityMatrix/SocialFoot/store.go:19 +0x1a3
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077369+00:00 app[web.1]: main.createUserHandler(0x7fd680, 0xc0000f4460, 0xc00012ce00)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077371+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/tmp.N9S5bJfo59/.go/src/github.com/InsanityMatrix/SocialFoot/main.go:114 +0x367
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077373+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x79e1a0, 0x7fd680, 0xc0000f4460, 0xc00012ce00)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077375+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077378+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/InsanityMatrix/SocialFoot/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0000f0000, 0x7fd680, 0xc0000f4460, 0xc00012cc00)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077380+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/tmp.N9S5bJfo59/.go/src/github.com/InsanityMatrix/SocialFoot/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:210 +0xe3
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077382+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc000084a90, 0x7fd680, 0xc0000f4460, 0xc00012cc00)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077384+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:2774 +0xa8
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077386+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00008f400, 0x7fdf00, 0xc000020a40)
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077388+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:1878 +0x851
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077391+00:00 app[web.1]: created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
2020-02-07T04:58:18.077393+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:2884 +0x2f4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `http.ListenAndServe()` does not return unless there is an error. It listens HTTP connections, and serves them. Because of that, the database initialization code in main never ran, and the HTTP connections are using a nil database connection.

Move the `http.ListenAndServe` to the bottom of `main()` to fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that because go is a multi-threaded language it would do network-related stuff like that on a separate thread. I see now that is not the case, thanks!

Comment: It does do that on separate goroutines. A new goroutine is created for each connection in `ListenAndServe`. If you need it to run listenAndServe in a separate thread, start it as `go func() { http.ListenAndServe(...)}()`